# SeekBar progress changes while scrolling the RecyclerView In android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, seekbar

I'm working on a chat application similar to What's Up. The issue I'm having is that I have the seek bar as well as the play icon in the recycler view. When I click the play symbol, the song is played, and the seek bar moves along with it.  It was working perfectly till here. The issue is that when I scroll the `recyclerView` while playing some songs, the progress of the seek bar is set to end automatically. If I scroll again, the seek bar progress position changes to according to song duration. I'm not sure why this is  happening. Does anyone have a solution for this? thanks in Advance :)

```
public class ChatContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Handler.Callback {
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    public Handler handler;
    private List<MessageInfo> messageInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ZIMGroupMemberInfo> memberList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Activity activity;
    Context context;
    String date = "";
    int count=0;
    boolean isPost = false;
    //boolean dateAvailable=false;
    String urlRegex = "^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\\.)?[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$";
    GetRequestWithEditPostGetDetailsModel.Data postData ;
    BaseViewHolder baseViewHolder;
    private int playingPosition;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Uri audioPathUri;
     Handler uiUpdateHandler = new Handler(this::handleMessage);

    private float denseness;
    private int width;

    private static final int MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR = 1845;
    public ChatContentAdapter (Activity activity,OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (ChatItemType.CHAT_ITEM_TYPE_RIGHT.value == viewType) {
            viewHolder = new ChatRightViewHolder(parent, onItemClickListener, activity);
        } else if (ChatItemType.CHAT_ITEM_TYPE_LEFT.value == viewType) {
            viewHolder = new ChatLeftViewHolder(parent, onItemClickListener, activity);
        } else if (ChatItemType.CHAT_ITEM_TYPE_CENTER.value == viewType){
            viewHolder = new ChatCenterViewHolder(parent,activity);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemView.setTag(position);
        MessageInfo messageInfo = messageInfoList.get(position);
        Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: "+messageInfo.isPlay());


        if(HomeActivity.homeActivity.cacheRepository.getMessageDate().equals("0")){
            HomeActivity.homeActivity.cacheRepository.saveMessageDate(Utilities.INSTANCE.getDateinYmd(messageInfo.getZIMMessage().getTimestamp()));
        }

        if (holder instanceof ChatLeftViewHolder) {
            ChatLeftViewHolder chat = (ChatLeftViewHolder) holder;
            chat.setMessageInfo(messageInfo,date,memberList,position,postData,messageInfoList.size());
            chat.seekBar.setProgress(messageInfoList.get(position).getSeekBarProgressValue());
            Log.i("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " +messageInfoList.get(position).getSeekBarProgressValue() );
            if (messageInfo.isPlay()){
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

            }else {
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                chat.seekBar.setProgress(0);
                chat.txtProcess.setText("00:00:00"+ "/"+ "00:00:00");
            }

            chat.ivPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SDKManager.sharedInstance().downloadMediaFile((ZIMMediaMessage) messageInfo.getZIMMessage(), ZIMMediaFileType.ORIGINAL_FILE, new ZIMMediaDownloadedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMediaDownloaded(ZIMMediaMessage message, ZIMError errorInfo) {
                           String path = new File(message.getFileLocalPath()).getAbsolutePath();
                            if (!path.isEmpty()){
                               Uri audioPath = Uri.parse(path);
                               setPlayer(audioPath,position,chat);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onMediaDownloadingProgress(ZIMMediaMessage message, long currentFileSize, long totalFileSize) {
                            AppLogger.getInstance().d("[%s] [onMediaDownloadingProgress] [currentFileSize:%d, totalFileSize:%d, message: %s]","TAG", currentFileSize, currentFileSize, message.getMessageID());
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            chat.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    if (fromUser) {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                            Log.i("TAG", "onProgressChanged: "+ progress);
                        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);

                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    if (((Activity)context)  != null) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                chat.imgPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                chat.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                chat.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                chat.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                try {
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

            });
        } else if (holder instanceof ChatRightViewHolder) {
            ChatRightViewHolder chat = (ChatRightViewHolder) holder;

            chat.setMessageInfo(messageInfo, date,memberList,position,postData, messageInfoList.size());

            chat.seekBar.setProgress(messageInfoList.get(position).getSeekBarProgressValue());

            if (messageInfo.isPlay()){
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

            }else {
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                chat.seekBar.setProgress(0);
                chat.txtProcess.setText("00:00:00"+ " / " + "00:00:00");
            }
            chat.ivPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SDKManager.sharedInstance().downloadMediaFile((ZIMMediaMessage) messageInfo.getZIMMessage(), ZIMMediaFileType.ORIGINAL_FILE, new ZIMMediaDownloadedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMediaDownloaded(ZIMMediaMessage message, ZIMError errorInfo) {
                            String path = new File(message.getFileLocalPath()).getAbsolutePath();
                            if (!path.isEmpty()){
                                Uri audioPath = Uri.parse(path);
                                setPlayerRight(audioPath,position, chat);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onMediaDownloadingProgress(ZIMMediaMessage message, long currentFileSize, long totalFileSize) {
                            AppLogger.getInstance().d("[%s] [onMediaDownloadingProgress] [currentFileSize:%d, totalFileSize:%d, message: %s]", "TAG", currentFileSize, currentFileSize, message.getMessageID());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            chat.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (((Activity) context) != null) {
                        if (fromUser) {
                            if (mediaPlayer!=null){
                                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress );
                                Log.i("TAG", "run: " + progress);
                                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    if (((Activity)context)  != null) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
//                                chat.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                                chat.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (((Activity)context)  != null) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
//                                chat.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                                chat.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                try {
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
      }
        }

    }

    private void updateForRightViewHolder(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, ChatRightViewHolder chat, SeekBar seekBar, Context context) {

        if (mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 100) {
            chat.txtProcess.setText(convertSecondsToHMmSs(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) + " / " + convertSecondsToHMmSs(this.mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000));
//            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            Log.i("TAG", "updateForRightViewHolder: " + playingPosition  + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            onItemClickListener.seekBarProgressValue(playingPosition,mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        }else {
            chat.txtProcess.setText(convertSecondsToHMmSs(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000));
//            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            Log.i("TAG", "updateForRightViewHolder: " + playingPosition  + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            onItemClickListener.seekBarProgressValue(playingPosition,mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        try{
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        if (ChatContentAdapter.this.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > -1) {
                            try {
                                updateForRightViewHolder(mediaPlayer,chat, seekBar, context);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
//            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
            seekBar.postDelayed(runnable,100);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setPlayerRight(Uri audioPath, int position, ChatRightViewHolder chat) {
        if (position == playingPosition){
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                messageInfoList.get(position).setPlay(false);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            } else {
                messageInfoList.get(position).setPlay(true);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }

        }else {
            if (playingPosition != -1) {
                onItemClickListener.getPosition(playingPosition);
            }
            playingPosition = position;
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            startRightMediaPlayer(audioPath, chat);
            messageInfoList.get(position).setPlay(true);
            chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }
    }

    private void startRightMediaPlayer(Uri audioPath, ChatRightViewHolder chat) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),audioPath);

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                chat.seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                chat.txtProcess.setText("00:00:00/"+convertSecondsToHMmSs(mp.getDuration() / 1000));
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.start();
        updateForRightViewHolder(mediaPlayer, chat, chat.seekBar, context);
    }



    private void setPlayer(Uri audioPath, int position, ChatLeftViewHolder chat) {
        if (position == playingPosition){

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                messageInfoList.get(position).setPlay(false);
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            } else {
                messageInfoList.get(position).setPlay(true);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        }else {
            if (playingPosition != -1) {
                onItemClickListener.getPosition(playingPosition);
            }
            playingPosition = position;
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

                mediaPlayer.release();
            }

            startMediaPlayer(audioPath,chat);
            messageInfoList.get(position).setPlay(true);
            chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }
    }

    private void startMediaPlayer(Uri audioPathUri, ChatLeftViewHolder chat) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),audioPathUri);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                chat.seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                chat.txtProcess.setText("00:00:00/"+convertSecondsToHMmSs(mp.getDuration() / 1000));
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                chat.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
            mediaPlayer.start();
            update(mediaPlayer, chat, chat.seekBar, context);

        chat.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (((Activity) context) != null) {
                    if (fromUser) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                                    Log.i("TAG", "run: " + progress);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    if (((Activity)context)  != null) {
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
//                                chat.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                                chat.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (((Activity)context)  != null) {
                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
//                            chat.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            chat.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            try {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                }
            }
        });
        }
    private void update(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, ChatLeftViewHolder chat, SeekBar seekBar, Context context) {

        if (mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 100) {
            chat.txtProcess.setText(convertSecondsToHMmSs(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) + " / " + convertSecondsToHMmSs(this.mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000));
//            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            onItemClickListener.seekBarProgressValue(playingPosition,mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        }else {
            chat.txtProcess.setText(convertSecondsToHMmSs(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000));
//            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        Handler handler = new Handler();

        try{
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        if (ChatContentAdapter.this.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > -1) {
                            try {
                                update(mediaPlayer,chat, seekBar, context);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
//            seekBar.postDelayed(runnable,500);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static String convertSecondsToHMmSs(int seconds) {
        long s = seconds % 60;
        long m = (seconds / 60) % 60;
        long h = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", h,m,s);
    }

    public void releaseMediaPlayer() {
//        if (null != baseViewHolder) {
//            updateNonPlayingView(baseViewHolder);
//        }

        mediaPlayer.release();

        mediaPlayer = null;
        playingPosition = -1;
    }

    public void updateNonPlayingView(BaseViewHolder holder) {
        holder.ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
        holder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        holder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        holder.seekBar.setEnabled(true);
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            uiUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR, 100);
            holder.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imgPause.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }else {
            uiUpdateHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR);
            holder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.ivPlayPause.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }

     public   void stopPlayer(){
        if (null != mediaPlayer) {
            releaseMediaPlayer();
        }

    }




    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return messageInfoList.get(position).getType().value;
    }





    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageInfoList.size();
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return messageInfoList.get(position).hashCode();
    }




//    @Override
//    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
//        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
//        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageInfoList.size()-1);
//    }

    public void add(MessageInfo messageInfo) {
        messageInfoList.add(0,messageInfo);
    }


    public void setPlayPause(int pos){
        messageInfoList.get(pos).setPlay(false);
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

    public void setSeekBar(int playingPosition ,int progressValue){
        messageInfoList.get(playingPosition).setSeekBarProgressValue(progressValue);
        notifyItemChanged(playingPosition);
        Log.i("TAG", "setSeekBarAdapter: " + playingPosition + progressValue);
    }

    public void addMessageToBottom(MessageInfo messageInfo){
        messageInfoList.add(messageInfo);
    }

    public void delete(MessageInfo info) {
        MessageInfo tempInfo = info;
        for (MessageInfo c : messageInfoList) {
            if (c.getZIMMessage().getMessageID() == info.getZIMMessage().getMessageID()) {
                tempInfo = c;
            }
        }
        messageInfoList.remove(tempInfo);
    }

    public void delete(long messageId) {
        MessageInfo tempInfo = null;
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < messageInfoList.size(); i++) {
            if (messageInfoList.get(i).getZIMMessage().getMessageID() == messageId) {
                tempInfo = messageInfoList.get(i);
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (tempInfo!=null){
            messageInfoList.remove(tempInfo);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public void clearInfo() {
        messageInfoList.clear();
    }

    public MessageInfo getMessage(int index) {
        if (messageInfoList != null && messageInfoList.size() > 0) {
            return messageInfoList.get(index);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void set(MessageInfo info){
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < messageInfoList.size(); i++) {
            if (messageInfoList.get(i).getZIMMessage().getLocalMessageID() == info.getZIMMessage().getLocalMessageID()) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (position!=0){
            messageInfoList.set(position,info);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }

    }

    public void updateMessageWhenDiffSentStatus(MessageInfo info){
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < messageInfoList.size(); i++) {
            ZIMMessage oldMessage = messageInfoList.get(i).getZIMMessage();
            ZIMMessage newMessage = info.getZIMMessage();
            if (oldMessage.getLocalMessageID() == info.getZIMMessage().getLocalMessageID() && newMessage.getSentStatus() != oldMessage.getSentStatus()) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (position!=0){
            messageInfoList.set(position,info);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    }

    public List<MessageInfo> getMessageInfoList(){
        return messageInfoList;
    }

    public void setMemberList(List<ZIMGroupMemberInfo> memberList){
        this.memberList = memberList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void setDetailsPost(GetRequestWithEditPostGetDetailsModel.Data data, int postPos) {
        this.postData = data;
        notifyItemChanged(postPos);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg ) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR: {
                baseViewHolder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                uiUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_SEEK_BAR, 100);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After scrolling the Recycler the position of seekbar thumb set to end.

Comment: Post your code. We can't debug a description of the problem.

Comment: sure bro will post my code

Comment: now You can check bro

Comment: Can't you think that you need to update the particular thing you are facing an issue with, or code where do you want help. Pasting 665 lines of code and expecting others to check the whole thing for you is not a good idea, I guess. it will be great you paste specific code

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing because You are getting the current progress of `seekbar` by using `messageInfoList.get(position).getSeekBarProgressValue()`  but you are not updating the value to the list.